# Mongodb find query performance issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have requirement like I need to search the fields which are dynamic in collection.
Example as shown below in one collection I want to search for title="Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800" but title will be changes from document to document.

First document title refers to "xyz" which is title for that document.
Second document title refers to "abc" which is title for that document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b988de0be31724e"),     
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "xyz"        
    },
   "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b9435dfgdf43554b"),     
    "abc" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "abc"        
    }
}
```

With following query I am able to get what I need. But It is taking 2 minutes of time for 10 million documents. Please suggest me to improve performance of query.

```
var titles = db.collection.distinct("mappingData.title"),
    titleVal = "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    query = { "$or": [] };

query["$or"] = titles.map(function (t){
    var q = {};
    q[t] = titleVal;
    return q;
});

db.collection.find(query);
```

Comment: The query is pretty much going to inspect every document in the collection based on the design pattern I see here. This is a very good reason why your keys should be consistent across all documents and really should just be called "title" instead. If the particular key names of "abc" etc are meant to be something significant, then then should be "data" instead. i.e `{ "title": "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800", "meta": "abc" }`

Comment: Thanks Blakes for your suggestion.  Design pattern is not by ourself. we are importing data from different sources so we are unable to change it dynamically. 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b988de0be31724e"),     
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
  ,
   "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b9435dfgdf43554b"),     
    "xyz" : "Sample title2",
   
}

Once we import above data we are updating documents with mapping data like:

  "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "xyz"        
    }

Comment: The point is it's the design doing the damage. Instead of searching in one static place for a specific value, and then possibly also multiple combinations of "meta" values paired with that, instead you are trying to force a query to look in *"all possible keys"* to find something that matches the value. I can't solve bad design, but can only advise that this is what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mention that you update your data with mapping data after the import. You could get much better performance if you copy the `title` value to a standardised field instead, for example `{ "title": "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800" }`. After adding an index to this field, a standard find query on `title` should run much faster.

Comment: Can you suggest me how we can update/copy with mapping data to another collection where we can add index as you suggested above.